# jquery hide show using index

Tags: jquery

I have multiple links to show related contents in same page show i used this,

```
$("#option .link").click(function(){
    Options=$("#option .link").index(this);
    $("#content").hide();
    $("#content:eq("+Options+")").show();
})
```

but this not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You used `#content` id  for element, but you should use only one id  in one page, so you should change all `#content` id   to class `.content`

```
$("#option .link").click(function(){
   Options=$("#option .link").index(this);
   $(".content").hide();
   $(".content:eq("+Options+")").show();
});
```

make this changes and try...

Comment: what this hell... why -1 for this post

Comment: Be careful; you're making `Options` an implicit global *which is bad*.   `var Options=$("#option .link").index(this);` would be better, and `var options=$("#option .link").index(this);` would be *even* better (reserve capital letters for constructors).

Answer (score 3):

There is only one element that can have `id` equal to `content`, because ids are unique. You probably need to switch to a class as you do with `.link`.

On another note, `Index` in your code is a global variable. Globals are to be avoided and there's really no need for one, so make it local with `var Index`.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is right.. But u should not use similar ID for more than one element.. Here, u used #content (it seems) for more than one element..

Try with class..

```
$("#option .link").click(function(){
    Options=$("#option .link").index(this);
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".content:eq("+Options+")").show();
})
```